# Zephyr writing tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, jira-zephyr

I read the documentation here: https://zephyrdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ZTD/Writing+Tests

about writing tests in zephyr, but I'm not sure what those tests are supposed to entail.

For example, that video shows one test case as "Verify app can be installed from store" or something similar to that.

But what does the test actually consist of? Is it code? Can you write Java JUnit tests in there?

What are you actually testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In at least one use case, it looks like the tester performs the test by some means other than through the Zephyr web interface and then updates the web UI manually:

> Typically, a tester will need to update the Zephyr for JIRA GUI for automated tests manually through the web interface.

Reference:
https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us/articles/204713195-Integrate-Selenium-JUnit-and-ANT-with-Zephyr-for-JIRA-and-ZAPI.

Answer (score 1):

In Zephyr you write the detailed test steps and expected results for them, something which is helpful during manual testing.
It helps non technical persons like BAs who are not keen in looking into the code to understand what your tests are actually doing. You can write some tests in Zephyr and pass it on Business for review.